# Getting info by an app

Tags: java, android

I've started to study how to create Android app. Right now I don't understand: how can app receive information from SQL db in the internet or from internet in general. Can anybody tell me?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Generally, I use an HTTP connection to retrieve data from a REST web service. I usually send JSON documents that I parse using Google Gson.

Comment: OK, to the downvoter, in what way is my advice wrong, misleading, or otherwise incorrect or not useful? I answered the question supplied. Why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but I'd imagine it'd be clearer if you explained how a REST web service helps with connecting an app to a SQL DB (which might seem obvious, but perhaps not to someone who couldn't come up with that in the first place). I definitely don't see a need to downvote this anyway.